# Bug? - Printing text from inside R chunk in RMD file formatted into the margin

Tags: r, r-markdown

In the following minimum example, it seems that it is fine to use cat to print out headings and kables / plots from r. But I can't print out simple text. It gets formatted in to the extreme right hand side, apparently into the margin. Here's the min example:

````
```{r  echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
if (TRUE) {
  cat(paste0("\n", "### 2.1   The Health Standards\n"))
  cat("\nLow indoor temperatures are associated with increased risks of respiratory")          
  monkeyr::who_guidance_kable()
}
```
````

And the output is like this:

[image: HTML Output]

Additional info: In the yaml header, I have put:

```
output: 
  distill::distill_article:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    theme: theme.css
```

And the css file is as follows:

```css
/* base variables */

/* Edit the CSS properties in this file to create a custom
   Distill theme. Only edit values in the right column
   for each row; values shown are the CSS defaults.
   To return any property to the default,
   you may set its value to: unset
   All rows must end with a semi-colon.                      */

/* Optional: embed custom fonts here with `@import`          */
/* This must remain at the top of this file.                 */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono');


html {
  /*-- Main font sizes --*/
  --title-size:      48px;
  --body-size:       1.0rem;
  --code-size:       14px;
  --aside-size:      12px;
  --fig-cap-size:    13px;
  /*-- Main font colors --*/
  --title-color:     #000000;
  --header-color:    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  --body-color:      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  --aside-color:     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  --fig-cap-color:   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  /*-- Specify custom fonts ~~~ must be imported above   --*/
  --heading-font:    "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  --mono-font:       "IBM Plex Mono", monospace;
  --body-font:       "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  --navbar-font:     "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;  /* websites + blogs only */
}




/*-- ARTICLE METADATA --*/
d-byline {
  --heading-size:    0.6rem;
  --heading-color:   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  --body-size:       0.8rem;
  --body-color:      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/*-- ARTICLE TABLE OF CONTENTS --*/
.d-contents {
  --heading-size:    18px;
  --contents-size:   13px;
}

/*-- ARTICLE APPENDIX --*/
d-appendix {
  --heading-size:    15px;
  --heading-color:   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  --text-size:       0.8em;
  --text-color:      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/*-- WEBSITE HEADER + FOOTER --*/
/* These properties only apply to Distill sites and blogs  */

.distill-site-header {
  --title-size:       18px;
  --text-color:       rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  --text-size:        15px;
  --hover-color:      white;
  --bkgd-color:       #0F2E3D;
}

.distill-site-footer {
  --text-color:       rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  --text-size:        15px;
  --hover-color:      white;
  --bkgd-color:       #0F2E3D;
}

/*-- Additional custom styles --*/
/* Add any additional CSS rules below                      */


/* Change appearance of headers */
```

Is there user error going on here? N.B the use case is to extend this to allow conditional inclusion of text and plots etc...

### Extra Detail:

I've extended my testing of this to add kables and plots inside a loop:

````
```{r  echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
if (TRUE) {
  cat(paste0("\n", "## ", section_number, ".X  Testing Loops ", mytempVarTitle))
  target_var_vec <- c("room", "tenure")
  for (i in 1:2) {
  
    # target_var <- "room"
    
    reg_data   <- monkeyr::get_reg_data(wranged_devices, wrangled_obs, target_reading = "temp")
    boxplot    <- monkeyr::get_reg_boxplot(reg_data, target_var_vec[i])
    print(boxplot)
    cat(paste0("\n", "#### Box Plot ", section_number, ".", i, " : ", target_var_vec[i]), "\n") 
    
    
    reg_kable  <- monkeyr::get_reg_kable(reg_data, target_var_vec[i])
    print(reg_kable)
    cat(paste0("\n", "#### Kable ", section_number, ".", i, " : ", target_var_vec[i]), "\n") 
    
    
    exposure_chart_data <- monkeyr::get_exposure_chart_data(wrangled_obs, wrangled_devices, target_var_vec[i])
    exposure_plot       <- monkeyr::get_exposure_plot(exposure_chart_data, target_var_vec[i])
    print(exposure_plot)
    cat(paste0("\n", "#### Plot ", section_number, ".", i, " : ", target_var_vec[i], "\n")) 
  
  }
  
  
  # BAIL TO FOCUS ON TEST
  knitr::knit_exit("</body></html>")
}
```
````

The results seem almost random. If I add in an extra "\n" or a "
" one of the captions will go into the margin like the text above.

[image]

Comment: You've obviously put a lot of effort into this. I'd strongly recommend doing what you can to make the example **minimal**. This will help both to identify and isolate the problem, and make it more approachable for anyone to help you.

Comment: For example, I don't have the `monkeyr` package and I try to avoid installing packages for single question on Stack Overflow. Does the problem persist if you do `knitr::kable(1)` instead of `monkeyr::who_guidance_kable()`? That way someone like me who doesn't have that package could work on the problem. Is the `if(TRUE)`  necessary? How much can you delete and simplify while still showing the problem?

Comment: I found the issue. Basically, the string that knitr sees needed more new lines so that ### type lines had white space either side. The reason this was not consistent is that some plot or kable elements appear to include at least one new line while others do not. So, in some cases, it worked.